# Как передать json файл на андроид устройство?

Tags: android, json, node.js

В программировании на андроид еще новичок, и интересно как для приложения сервер который будет передавать json файл на устройство.

Может есть где-то готовый сервер или есть что почитать, желательно на русском?

Comment: На сервере admin организует тебе api для того чтобы ты мог получать данные с сервера. С помощью retrofit (либо что ближе) отправляешь запрос на получение данных. Вот кратко логика работы.

Comment: Глава 15. API REST и JSON - в книге "Web-разработка с применением Node.js и Express", Итан Браун.

Comment: На данный момент мне самому нужно написать такой сервер) Так что конкретно можно почитать или может есть где готовый сервер, в котором можно разобраться ?